# MKMapView change current location blimp color

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

Hey I'm using a MKMapView and I need the current location blimp (normally blue with little animated fading rings around) to be red. I have seen this done on apps like opentable. Just wondering how I do it to fit in with my red color scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write this single line :-

```
 mapView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Or Implement this delegate Method :-

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation 
{
  MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
  annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
  return annView;
}
```